# tensorflow error: InvalidArgumentError: Shape mismatch in tuple component 1. Expected [1], got [5]

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to construct a batch of (wav_file, label) pair.
wav file labels and paths are listed in dev.csv.
below code is not working,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

threads = 1
batch_size = 5
global record_defaults
record_defaults = [['/Users/phoenix/workspace/dataset/data_thchs30/dev/A11_101.wav'], ['8.26'], ['七十 年代 末 我 外出 求学 母亲 叮咛 我 吃饭 要 细嚼慢咽 学习 要 深 钻 细 研']]

def read_record(filename_queue, num_records):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read_up_to(filename_queue, num_records)
    wav_filename, duration, transcript = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults, field_delim=",")

    wav_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    wav_key, wav_value = wav_reader.read_up_to(tf.train.string_input_producer(wav_filename, shuffle=False, capacity=num_records), num_records)
    return [wav_key, transcript] # throw errors
    # return [wav_key, wav_value]  # works
    # return [wav_filename, duration, transcript]   # works

data_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once('dev.csv'), shuffle=False)  
batch_data = [read_record(data_queue, batch_size) for _ in range(threads)]
capacity = threads * batch_size
batch_values = tf.train.batch_join(batch_data, batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity, enqueue_many=True)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    print(coord)
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    print("threads num: " + str(threads))
    try:
        step = 0
        while not coord.should_stop():
            step += 1
            feat = sess.run([batch_values])
            print("line:", step, feat)

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print(' training for 1 epochs, %d steps', step)
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

throw errors below, how can I fix it?:

[image]

dev.csv content as below:

> /Users/phoenix/workspace/dataset/data_thchs30/dev/A11_101.wav,8.26,qi shi nian dai mo wo wai chu qiu xue
>
> /Users/phoenix/workspace/dataset/data_thchs30/dev/A11_119.wav,6.9,chen yun tong shi yao qiu gan bu men ren zhen xue xi

Answer (score 0):

I tried to rewrite your code like this.

This is my observation.

1. The error is no longer thrown. And the values are returned.
2. An obvious discrepancy is that the size of the batch for *transcript* is double that specified. So it is 4 instead of 2. It doubles for some reason. No such problem for the audio binary.
3. > `shapes=[tf.TensorShape(()),tf.TensorShape(batch_size,)]` is based on an error I saw which mentioned that I have to specify this using `TensorShape`. I didn't find the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue) of any help but it is mentioned there.

> shapes: (Optional.) A list of fully-defined TensorShape objects with the same length as dtypes, or None.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

threads = 1
batch_size = 2
record_defaults = [['D:/male.wav'], ['8.26'], ['七十 年代 末 我 外出 求学 母亲 叮咛 我 吃饭 要 细嚼慢咽 学习 要 深 钻 细 研']]


def readbatch(data_queue) :

    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _, rows = reader.read_up_to(data_queue, batch_size)
    wav_filename, duration, transcript = tf.decode_csv(rows, record_defaults,field_delim=",")
    audioreader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    _, audio = audioreader.read( tf.train.string_input_producer(wav_filename) )
    return [audio,transcript]

data_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
                tf.train.match_filenames_once('D:/Book1.csv'), shuffle=False)

batch_data = [readbatch(data_queue) for _ in range(threads)]
capacity = threads * batch_size
batch_values = tf.train.batch_join(batch_data, shapes=[tf.TensorShape(()),tf.TensorShape(batch_size,)], capacity=capacity, batch_size=batch_size, enqueue_many=False )

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    try:
        step = 0
        while not coord.should_stop():
            step += 1
            feat = sess.run([batch_values])
            audio = feat[0][0]
            print ('Size of audio is ' + str(audio.size))
            script = feat[0][1]
            print ('Size of script is ' + str(script.size))
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print(' training for 1 epochs, %d steps', step)
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

A sample dataset proves that there is an extra pair.

```
[[array([b'Text2', b'Text1'], dtype=object), array([[b'Translation-1', b'Translation-2'],
       [b'Translation-1', b'Translation-2']], dtype=object)]]
```

Comment: You are not reading the actual wav files like I did using WholeFileReader, this is what causing the problems!

Comment: Agreed. There is another set when the Wav files are read. WIll try until someone pitches in.

Comment: Edited with some improvement. You may also consider the [data API.](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)

Comment: can you help in this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225332/invalid-argument-in0-mismatch-in1-shape ?